# Private key from environment variable instead of file in Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, vercel

I need to connect to Google Cloud Firestore from my Next.js serverless function hosted in Vercel. I already have a service account set up, but all the docs out there rely on the credentials being a *file*, while I'd like to use *environment variables* (more natural in Vercel platform).

[Example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore/v/0.9.0):

```
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json',
});
```

I cannot use `keyFilename`, I'd rather pass the service account email and private key explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

## Working code:

```
const projectId = process.env.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID;
const email = process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL;
const key = process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');

const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: projectId,
  credentials: {
    client_email: email,
    private_key: key,
  },
});
```

Please note that my `GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY` env var has literal `\n`s, exactly as Google Cloud's JSON comes, so I use `.replace()` on it to translate them to actual newlines. This is actually only needed in my local environment, where I use `.env.local`, since Vercel env vars can take actual newlines.

## Source

The `settings` object (argument for the constructor `Firestore()`) is poorly documented, but I was able to figure it out by myself grepping through the source code, where I found:

```
node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts
Line 217:

/**
 * Settings used to directly configure a `Firestore` instance.
 */
export interface Settings {
  /**
   * The project ID from the Google Developer's Console, e.g.
   * 'grape-spaceship-123'. We will also check the environment variable
   * GCLOUD_PROJECT for your project ID.  Can be omitted in environments that
   * support {@link https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication Application
   * Default Credentials}
   */
  projectId?: string;

  /** The hostname to connect to. */
  host?: string;

  /** The port to connect to. */
  port?: number;

  /**
   * Local file containing the Service Account credentials as downloaded from
   * the Google Developers Console. Can  be omitted in environments that
   * support {@link https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication Application
   * Default Credentials}. To configure Firestore with custom credentials, use
   * the `credentials` property to provide the `client_email` and
   * `private_key` of your service account.
   */
  keyFilename?: string;

  /**
   * The 'client_email' and 'private_key' properties of the service account
   * to use with your Firestore project. Can be omitted in environments that
   * support {@link https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication Application
   * Default Credentials}. If your credentials are stored in a JSON file, you
   * can specify a `keyFilename` instead.
   */
  credentials?: {client_email?: string; private_key?: string};

  /** Whether to use SSL when connecting. */
  ssl?: boolean;

  /**
   * The maximum number of idle GRPC channels to keep. A smaller number of idle
   * channels reduces memory usage but increases request latency for clients
   * with fluctuating request rates. If set to 0, shuts down all GRPC channels
   * when the client becomes idle. Defaults to 1.
   */
  maxIdleChannels?: number;

  /**
   * Whether to use `BigInt` for integer types when deserializing Firestore
   * Documents. Regardless of magnitude, all integer values are returned as
   * `BigInt` to match the precision of the Firestore backend. Floating point
   * numbers continue to use JavaScript's `number` type.
   */
  useBigInt?: boolean;

  /**
   * Whether to skip nested properties that are set to `undefined` during
   * object serialization. If set to `true`, these properties are skipped
   * and not written to Firestore. If set `false` or omitted, the SDK throws
   * an exception when it encounters properties of type `undefined`.
   */
  ignoreUndefinedProperties?: boolean;

  [key: string]: any; // Accept other properties, such as GRPC settings.
}
```

Comment: this was helpful thanks I had to copy the whole property value of "private_key"
`"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nblab172342390809Blahblah\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",`

Answer (score 2):

Working with **Firebase Admin SDK 11.9.0**

```
import { initializeApp, getApps, cert } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    credential: cert({
      projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY?.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
    }),
  });
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
```